# regular expression to an English description

Tags: regex

I'm really struggling with regular expressions. I have to give English descriptions of the following regular expressions can anyone please please please help me..

- i. a(aa)*
- ii. a(b*ab*ab*)*
- iii. b(b*ab*ab*)*

heres my attempts but everyone else in the class has seems to have shorter answers.

- i. Find a "a" followed by either zero or more times "aa"s should be seen
- ii. Find a "a" followed by either zero or more times of this pattern :
  (zero or more times "b" followed by zero or more times "ab" followed by zero or more times "ab")
- iii. Find a "b" followed by either zero or more times of this pattern :
  (zero or more times "b" followed by zero or more times "ab" followed by zero or more times "ab")

Comment: Are you looking for one regex to match all three of those rules, or do you want three different ones?

Comment: yes they are actual regexes that need to be translated into english

Comment: Just paste them at [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and you'll get an explanation. Or at [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) and you'll get a *cool* graphical explanation.

Answer (score 4):

If those strings are actual regexes, they (completely) match the following:

1. An odd number of `a`s.
2. A string starting with `a`, followed by any combination of `a`s and `b`s, with an overall odd number of `a`s.
3. A string starting with `b`, followed by any combination of `a`s and `b`s, with an overall even number of `a`s. <sub>Edge case: If the string contains more than one `b`, it needs to contain at least two `a`s.</sub>

"Any combination" includes zero instances of each character.

Some possible matches for 1.:

```
a
aaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaaa etc.
```

Some possible matches for 2.:

```
a
aaa
ababa
aaab
abbbbbbbbaa
ababababababa
```

Some possible matches for 3.:

```
b
baa
baba
baaaaaba
bbbbbbbbbbaa
bababababbbbb
```

Comment: Any comment from the downvoter? Is there an error in my explanation?

Comment: 2. and 3. Not **any** combination of as and bs! Only single as combined with any number of bs with an overall odd number of as.

Comment: @Fischermaen: No. Read the regexes again (and test them if you don't believe me). `a(b*ab*ab*)*` matches `abbbabababababababbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaba`.

Comment: @FailedDev: It depends whether you allow submatches or complete matches. I'm working from the assumption that complete matches are required.

Comment: @TimPietzcker No it's perfectly fine. This is the straightforward explanation anyone would give.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I don't see how you are getting the trailing a's in 2. Can you please explain

Comment: @TimPietzcker Nevermind just needed to take a second look at the language i was assuming it was (ab)* not a b* sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free tool [Ultrapico Express](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) which can help. Just run a match on any of the regexes you mentioned, then it should be relatively easy to translate into regular English;

[image: Ultrapico Express parsing a regex]

Answer (score 0):

i - an odd number of a's, with at least one a.
ii - an odd number of a's, with at least one a, and 0 or more b's between each pair of a's.

Your attempted solutions seem correct, but I would expect your professor will complain that you're description is rephrasing the RE and is not an English description of the result.

I'll leave iii back to you to re-word (mainly because it's more difficult than the other two and I'm lazy this morning!)

Comment: The rules are more complicated than that.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker -- please explain how - I don't see how your answers are different than mine.

Comment: ii needs to *start* with a. And the "0 or more b's" are not only possible between each pair of a's but anywhere in the string (except of course the beginning).

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I agree that I failed to state it must start with an a. The part about where b's are -- you disagree that each pair of a's has 0 or more b's between them because they can appear elsewhere? You might notice that there is no elsewhere in this string... only a's and b's.

Comment: Uh, OK, I probably read too much into that word "pair", thinking you meant the pairs of `a`s in each group. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Let me hint you a bit:

- How would you describe the regular expression 'a'? How about 'aa'?. Ok, now, how would you describe the expression 'a*' and '(aa)*' ? For the latter there is a pattern which is interesting. Now, try to combine them. What is a(aa)* ? If you write down a couple of specimens for the regular language, there is a pattern you can spot.
- Odd and even plays a role here.

The trick is to cut up the regular expression and understand each part. Then write down a couple of strings which are in the language the RE decides. Then look for a pattern. My guess is that this is what your TA/Prof wants you to do in order to understand the relationsship between an RE and the language it decides.

Answer (score 0):

1. An odd number of as.
2. A string starting with a, followed by any combination of single as and multiple bs (zero or more), with an overall odd number of as.
3. A string starting with b, followed by any combination of single as and multiple bs (zero or more), with an overall even number of as.

Comment: Not single `a`s. The `b`s inside the repeated group are completely optional.